# Add an ask inside an ask

Tags: netlogo

I want to do the following.

```
to some-function
    let agent-set turtles with [some-criteria]
    ask agent-set [do-this]
end
```

But I also want each `turtle` to update its owner variables after each agent does `do-this`.

Something like,

```
to some-function
    let agent-set turtles with [some-criteria]
    ask agent-set [
       do-this
       ask turtles [update-owned-variables]
    ]
end
```

But of course, you can't `ask turtles` inside an agent's local command.

I am guessing that I have to loop through each of `agent-set`, but I don't know how to do that either. I would prefer to not do that.

Comment: I see nobody has attempted to answer this. My gut feeling is that, if I wanted all turtles to update their variables any time any turtle did something then I have a ticking problem. Generally you want the tick to represent some meaningful amount of time, so all the things that have to happen actually happen within one tick. If the turtles are updating their variables each time any turtle does something, that suggests that one turtle is meaningful. Could you explain more why they all need to update and maybe we can think of a different approach that avoids the problem entirely.

Comment: Ohh, okay. My idea was to make the turtles occupy unoccupied patches near other turtles. But for this, each time a turtle moves to a new location, the next set of turtles have to refresh their movable patches. As you know from my other question that you answered, for this particular example, I know the solution. But, that was because a global function `any? other turtles-here` was already defined to use it. If one turtle had to act depending on variables that other turtles store, then this method may not work. I hope I was able to convey my idea.

Comment: My interpretation of this (and looking at the other question) is that the turtle doesn't actually need to know its value of movable-patches until it is about to move. So you don't need to update the variable for all turtles each time a turtle moves, you just need to update it for the specific turtle that is about to move before moving it. This also has the advantage of being MUCH more efficient because only one turtle needs to calculate where you have all turtles calculating. In addition, you can use `let` instead of storing it as a `turtles-own` variable.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. That is more efficient. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If that 'solves' your problem, could you delete this question? It's not really useful for future StackOverflow visitors. By the way, this sort of issue is exactly why the NetLogo designers made it very difficult to do nested `ask` over all turtles - it's very easy to accidentally make the model extremely slow with nesting